# How does Tensorflow 1.x traverse the computation graph given a Tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

This question is with regards to the low-level Tensorflow 1.x API. Given a `Tensor` to `Session.run()`, I am unclear as how to how Tensorflow traverses the computation graph.

Say I have some code like this:

```
a = tf.constant(1.0)
b = tf.subtract(a, 1.0)
c = tf.add(b, 2.0)
d = tf.multiply(c,3)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(d)
```

The subtract, add, and multiply operations are not all stored in the Tensor `d`, right? I know the `Tensor` object have `graph` and `op` fields; are these fields some how accessed recursively to get all the operations required to compute `d`?

EDIT: adding output

```
print(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())
node {
  name: "Const"
  op: "Const"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "value"
    value {
      tensor {
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        tensor_shape {
        }
        float_val: 1.0
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "Sub/y"
  op: "Const"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "value"
    value {
      tensor {
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        tensor_shape {
        }
        float_val: 1.0
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "Sub"
  op: "Sub"
  input: "Const"
  input: "Sub/y"
  attr {
    key: "T"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "Add/y"
  op: "Const"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "value"
    value {
      tensor {
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        tensor_shape {
        }
        float_val: 2.0
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "Add"
  op: "Add"
  input: "Sub"
  input: "Add/y"
  attr {
    key: "T"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "Mul/y"
  op: "Const"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "value"
    value {
      tensor {
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        tensor_shape {
        }
        float_val: 3.0
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "Mul"
  op: "Mul"
  input: "Add"
  input: "Mul/y"
  attr {
    key: "T"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
}
versions {
  producer: 38
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the whole point of Tensorflow's static computational graph. When you build the graph, Tensorflow implicitly builds a static graph in the background. Then, when you execute a node in the graph, Tensorflow knows the exact set of operations that lead to that node. This has several benefits:

1. Saves computation, since only subgraphs that lead to the node you want will be executed.
2. The whole computation is divided into small differentiable pieces.
3. Each part of the model can be executed on a different device, thus huge acceleration.

Use this command, to see the inputs of each node:

```
print(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())
```

For example, if you execute this on your small graph, you will see the following, starting from the node `d = tf.multiply(c,3)`:

```
name: "Mul"
op: "Mul"
input: "Add"
```

Then `c = tf.add(b, 2.0)`:

```
name: "Add"
op: "Add"
input: "Sub"
```

Then `b = tf.subtract(a, 1.0)`:

```
name: "Sub"
op: "Sub"
input: "Const"
```

And finally `a = tf.constant(1.0)`:

```
name: "Const"
op: "Const"
```

Comment: Thanks gorjan, this makes sense. So from `d`, TF can find the op (`d.op`), which is multiply in this case, and then TF can find the op's inputs (which are Tensor's), and then find their ops, and so on, essentially doing a DFS from `d`.

Comment: Just saw your edits. I ran the command and pasted the output to the Question. It looks like all the constant operands are named with `/y` for some reason.

Comment: TBH, I am not a developer of Tensorflow by any means, just pointing out stuff that I read and my intuition. When it comes to how the operations in the background are computed, I don't want to share information that I am not certain about.

Comment: Sure, no problem! It looks like in TF's graph, the nodes are operations and edges are Tensors. I suppose it could be the other way around, too (Tensors 
being nodes and operations being edges). But that's another discussion altogether :)

Comment: The nodes are the operations. The output of each op is a tensor. An edge between two nodes, is the reference of the type/shape etc of Tensor that will flow from one node to the other.